# Perl: how can i read a specific cookie value stored by Firefox

Tags: perl, firefox, cookies

I'm currently developing a script in Perl as want to recover a specific cookie that Facebook is currently storing in my browser.
The cookie name is Datr and i've tried multiple Perl modules such as HTTP::Cookies, CGI::Cookie and so forth, without success.

What i wanna do is simple and i need to do it via Perl: storing the Datr value (which changes dynamically) into a new variable in my Perl script.

I decided to set a test cookie and try to read its value, but neither the script returns something nor the browser (Mozilla) seems to store my cookie.
Here is the code i used:

```
#!bin/perl

use CGI;

$query = new CGI;

##setting a new cookie into the browser
$cookie = $query->cookie(-name=>'MY_COOKIE',
             -value=>'HelloWorld',
             -domain=>'facebook.com',
             -expires=>'+4h');

##retrieving cookie value
$theCookie = $query->cookie('MY_COOKIE');
```

Please help me with this as i'm going crazy!
thanks

First of all i would like to thanks all of you for the prompt reply.

To Dave: thanks for your very good answer on this. Yes i'm aware that Firefox can read the Datr value via GUI, but actually i need to read it with Perl code, because my original script features a specific SSL request which actually needs the Datr value. Facebook has arealdy answered on Datr ''understanding'' (http://www.adweek.com/digital/datr-cookie-belgium/) and seems an interesting side-topic. Getting back to my original request, i'm quite sure that Firefox stores all cookies value locally in some sort of .sqlite db called cookie.sqlite, and i can get there! If a try to read it ''manually'', i can see the Datr string, but that's not going to fix anything as i do not want to update my PL script each and every time i want to perform any sort of SSL request to FB!! that's the point.

My original question could be reformulated as follows: is there any way to query the .sqlite cookie db created by Firefox in order to retreive the Datr cookie and store it in a Perl variable? Please bear in mind that i don't want to set an absolute ''path to file'' in my PL script, as it is supposed to be executed either in Linux or any other OS (Windows, OSx..).

Thanks in advace for any further reply on this subject.

Comment: No way, unless you run your script on facebook domain, or use some other script on the same machine where firefox resides.

Comment: Browsers aren't stupid. They only accept and return cookies for your domain.

Answer (score 4):

There are two steps to reading a cookie.

1. Accessing the value of the cookie.
2. Understanding that value.

Modules like the ones you mention, only deal with the first step. They allow you to write cookie headers into your web application's responses and read cookie headers from requests that come into your web application. But they will only read or write cookies for the domain that your web application is running on. It's very unlikely that your application is running on facebook.com, therefore these modules are going to be useless to you.

However, all is not lost. Firefox will give you access to any cookies that are stored in the browser. I assume you already know that (as you know the name of the cookie you're interested in) but in case you don't - choose "preferences" from the hamburger menu and then "privacy"; that page has a "remove individual cookies" link.

So you can see the contents of the datr cookie. I'm looking at mine right now. It's string of 24 random-looking characters.

And that's the next problem. How do you interpret that string? Only Facebook can answer that. It's possible that it is a hash containing all sorts of interesting data. But it will be almost impossible to prove that. More likely (because this is, I think, best practice) it's just a random string of characters which is a key into some data store that is held somewhere within Facebook's system.

So it's either a well-encrypted secret or a random string. Either way it's useless to you.

Getting the value of a cookie is easy. Understanding that value is (usually) impossible.

**Update:** So actually, now you've redefined the question completely. It's not about cookies at all. It's about reading data from an SQLite database. And for that you should look at [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite). If you have any more specific questions about how to do this, then please ask a new question.

Comment: Re: `Either way it's useless to you.` not really if OP intends to hijack sessions. ;)

Comment: There is, of course, the possibility of forcing the user's traffic through a proxy (possibly abusing stupid software already installed on the computer such as an antivirus or manufacturer's software, and playing with the cookies.

Comment: In such case hosts file is also a candidate.

Comment: Hi guys and thanks for your answers. I edited my original request with further information. Let me know your idea on this. Thx

Comment: Thanks Dave. Actually, the question is the same which is "getting a cookie value stored by Firefox". I've simply suggested a possible solution to it...anyway i've already figured out a script solving the problem via DBI module, as suggested by you. Now i'm traveling, but i will post the code asap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i've figured out. It works well. I didn't use absolute path (at least, directly) therefore, in theory, it should work also in Windows (having Perl on it) and Mac OS, but i didn't test it. It simply search the .sqlite db into the system and once found it returns the value of Datr stored by Firefox.

```
#!/bin/perl

 use File::Find::Rule;
 use DBI;
 use strict;

  my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                             ->name('firefox', 'cookies.sqlite') 
                             ->in( '/home' ); 

my @matches = grep { /firefox/i && /mozilla/i } @files; 
print "DB PATH: @matches\n\n";

####### connect to .sqlite database

my $database = @matches[0];

my $dbfile = "$database";
my $dsn      = "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile"; #set path to db
my $user     = ""; 
my $password = "";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {
   PrintError       => 0, 
   RaiseError       => 1, 
   });
print "Database opened successfully\n\n";


my $stmt = "SELECT VALUE FROM moz_cookies WHERE NAME='datr'"; 
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt );
my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

if($rv < 0) {
  print $DBI::errstr;
}

my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array(); #fetching data of sth into a new array

print "COOKIE VALUE: @row"; #print data

print "\n\nOperation done successfully\n";
```